# Get Column names using pipes r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na

I am trying to get column names of NA columns using named pipes in R:-

```
df <- structure(data.frame(id = c(1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                 cat = c("SS","SS", "SS", "SV", "SV", "SV"),
                 val = c(220L, 222L, 223L, NA,NA, 2206L)),
                .Names = c("id", "cat", "val"), class = "data.frame",
                  row.names = c(NA,-6L)) 

sapply(df, function(x) ((sum(is.na(x))))*.01)%>%
  stack %>% rev %>% filter(values > 0) %>% setNames(nm=c("variable", "missing"))%>%
paste0(colnames ->NulCols)
```

But the code gives out error. 
Error in paste0(., NulCols <- colnames) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Want to create a list of NA Columns using named pipes only.

Comment: for the last paste0, just do pull(variable) ? Are you trying to get names of columns with > 1 NA?

Comment: No. this is purely for learning purpose.

Answer (score 0):

For the example you have given you can use pull in order to get the column names as follows;

```
library(dplyr)
df <- structure(data.frame(id = c(1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                           cat = c("SS","SS", "SS", "SV", "SV", "SV"),
                           val = c(220L, 222L, 223L, NA,NA, 2206L)),
                .Names = c("id", "cat", "val"), class = "data.frame",
                row.names = c(NA,-6L))

sapply(df, function(x) ((sum(is.na(x))))*.01) %>%
  stack %>% 
  rev %>% 
  filter(values > 0) %>% 
  setNames(nm = c("variable", "missing")) %>%
  pull(variable) %>%
  as.character(.) -> NulCols
```

In general if what you are trying to get only is the name of columns containing any NA you can do that using Base R in a much easier way, there are lots of ways but here are some that you can use;

```
# Method 1
colnames(df)[!complete.cases(t(df))]

# Method 2
names(df)[sapply(df, anyNA)]

# Method 3
names(df)[!!colSums(is.na(df))]
```

If using pipe is essential for you, you can also use something like this;

```
df %>% 
  select_if(function(x) any(is.na(x))) %>%
  colnames(.) -> NulCols
```